# Fill an Array with Custom Objects in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift

For my Current project I'd like to fill a TableView from my CoreData DB.

I've a Class named Movies(movieNAme, cinemaName, rate)

Thanks to this function :

```
    var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Movies")
    myMovies = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
```

However, I'd like to specify the type of the objects in this array(I want an Array of object Movie)

I've tried that

```
    var myMovies:Array<Films> ...
```

but with the Array type, I don't have access to the objectAtIndex method

Any ideas to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer ! But I decided to use this instead :

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:    NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:MainTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MainTableViewCell

    println((myMovies.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Movies).name)
    cell.CellTitle.text = (myMovies.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as Movies).MovieName)
    return cell
}
```

But it doesn't work either...

EDIT : It works now ! I missed to link my class to my Entity in CoreData ! Sorry

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do myMovies[0], same as objectAtIndex, the reason you don't have objectAtIndex is because it is a Swift array, you can just access the index using []